# Account association incorrect username?

Tags: support, linked-accounts

Today i associated my account with meta.stackoverflow.com, but username is not transferred. It just says 'user164226'. But when i associated webmasters.stackexchange.com (and many others), username was correct. Is it a bug on meta?

Comment: As the username should be the same in the other accounts you have, I would say it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to StackOverflow, and then go to your profile page, and then to the accounts tab, then at the bottom of the page, you should see a button saying "Copy your Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts"; now, if that's not going to have any adverse affects for you, try that - does that fix it?

Comment: I noticed these buttons and indeed it is a fix. But for example on mentioned webmasters.stackexchange.com i do not have to click on "Copy your Stack Overflow profile to all Stack Exchange accounts", it just works, so i think it is a bug. Nevermind, i am accepting this answer.

Comment: @tomas at the time of new account creation (on any site) we copy info from the profile with the *highest reputation in the network* to your profile.

Comment: @Jeff But this is exactly what did not happened. I have highest rep on SO and profile info was copied everytime i created new account on SE sites. Except for meta.